# How can use another database instead of foodmart

Tags: postgresql, saiku

I am not much familiar with saiku reporting. When I run the saiku reporting this display cube for foodmart db. But I want to use database from postgresql. For that I made one connection file. Added driver.jar file in to web-inf/lib folder. But I cant seen database in cube.

What we can only use foodmart database ? Cant we use another database?

Comment: PostgreSQL and Saiku works great together. Do you have any OLAP schema defined for your PostgreSQL data? To make it work you need connection file, XML schema for OLAP cube and data in database.

Comment: No, I am just putting blank xml file in one folder. We have to require   any schema? and where to put this shema? Please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sample Data**

Create sample data in PostgreSQL:

```
create table olap_data(id serial, measure int, dim varchar);

insert into olap_data (measure, dim) select * from generate_series(1,10) cross join (values ('a'), ('b'),('c')) a;

select * from olap_data;
```

**Connection File**

Add connection file (name does not matter, I'm using `dummy_test`).

Destination: `/saiku-server/tomcat/webapps/saiku/WEB-INF/classes/saiku-datasources/dummy_test`

Content:

```
type=OLAP
name=Financial
driver=mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver
location=jdbc:mondrian:Jdbc=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tgr; \
Catalog=/home/Applications/Saiku/saiku-server/tomcat/webapps/saiku/WEB-INF/classes/foodmart/dummy_cube.xml;JdbcDrivers=org.postgresql.Driver;
username=YourUsername
password=YourPassword
```

Do not forget to set correct connection string, username and password.

**Add OLAP schema definition**

Destination: `/home/Applications/Saiku/saiku-server/tomcat/webapps/saiku/WEB-INF/classes/foodmart/dummy_cube.xml` (has to match path defined in data source definition file).

Content:

```
<Schema name="New Schema1">
  <Cube name="Sample Cube" visible="true" cache="true" enabled="true">
    <Table name="olap_data" schema="public">
    </Table>
    <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" foreignKey="id" name="Sample Dimension">
      <Hierarchy name="Sample Hiearchy" visible="true" hasAll="true">
        <Table name="olap_data" schema="public">
        </Table>
        <Level name="Sample Level" visible="true" column="dim" uniqueMembers="false">
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Measure name="Measure" column="measure" aggregator="sum" visible="true">
    </Measure>
  </Cube>
</Schema>
```

**Make it work**

Restart Saiku

Clear cache from browser

Now you should see sample cube in Saiku[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I find the cube. For every table I have to made schema? I can not find all the tables from database ?

Comment: Schema can consist of several cubes. Typically, you will have more tables for every cube. Typical cube consists of fact table (with measures) and dimensions. You really should [read this](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php). You can design schemas in [Schema Workbench](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mondrian/files/schema%20workbench/) If you know R I have a package to generate schema for single tables on [github](https://github.com/tomasgreif/mondrianr)